# Unzipping a directory/file in Java

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public static void unzip(final File archive) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    ZipInputStream zipInput = null;
    try
    {
        zipInput = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(archive));
        ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
        while ((zipEntry = zipInput.getNextEntry()) != null)
        {
            String ename = zipEntry.getName();
            final int pos = ename.lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
            if (pos >= 0)
            {
                ename = ename.substring(pos + 1);
            }
            final FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(archive.getParent() + File.separatorChar + ename);
            int data = 0;
            try
            {
                while ((data = zipInput.read()) != -1)
                {
                    outputFile.write(data);
                }
            }catch (final Exception e)
            {
                LOGGER.error( e);
            }finally
            {
                outputFile.close();
            }

        }

    }catch (final Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Error when zipping file ( "+archive.getPath()+" )", e);
    }finally
    {
        if(zipInput !=null)
        {
            zipInput.close();
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is, what does it mean when I get the value -1 from the following line:

```
(data = zipInput.read()) != -1
```

I'm guessing it's the reason why the zip file is not being unzipped properly.

Comment: It just means to read until it reaches the end of the archive.

Comment: Copying a file byte by byte is not the most efficient way to do it. Consider using a larger buffer.

Comment: Here is the javadoc for read(), it returns -1 when the end of the archive is reached. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html#read--

Comment: @matt your two comments would have made a good answer. Let me know if you want to post one, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Classic XY problem. Your guess is mistaken. You need to post the *actual problem* you are having.

Answer (score 1):

It's an expected value to be returned by an `InputStream` which has no content left to read.

From [`InputStream`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) :

> Returns:
>   the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.